# addEventListener not calling my function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I've created a event listener, however, it doesn't seem to call my function. I'm not sure if it is because the element is in a innerHTML or what. I know the event listener itself is listening because if I replace the function with console.log, I can get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Weather App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--********************* Project **************************-->
        <form>
            <div id="citySearchForm"></div>
            <div id="weather"></div>
            <p><span id="temp"></span></p>
            <p><span id="wind"></span></p>
        </form>
        <!--******************* Script Files **********************-->
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js code:

```
var defaultDiv = true;
var cityName;
var citySearch = document.getElementById('citySearchForm');
if(defaultDiv === true) {
    citySearch.innerHTML += '<p>Choose a city:</p>'+
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a city" id="getCitiesInput"></input>'+
    '<button type="submit">Search</button>';
 } else {
     citySearch.innerHTML += '<p>Select the correct city:</p>'+
     '<select id="resultOptions">'+ 
     '<option value='+ "" + '></option>'+
     '</select>'+
     '<button type="submit">See Results</button>';
 };
console.log(cityName);
citySearch.addEventListener("submit", searchFormFunc);

function searchFormFunc(e) {
     console.log('working');
     if(defaultDiv === true) {
         console.log('fired 1');
         cityName = document.getElementById('getCitiesInput').value;
         console.log(cityName);
         defaultDiv = false;
     } else {
         console.log('fired 2');
         selectedCity = document.getElementById('resultOptions').value;
         console.log(selectedCity);
     }
}
```

Comment: You defined functions inside the handler, but you're not calling them. Seems like you don't want the functions at all. Just remove `function searchCity(e){` and `function getCityResults(e){` and their closing braces.

Comment: What is `searchFormFunc` supposed to do? Right now it creates two functions that never get called, makes two log messages and exits, losing all references to both functions, making them inaccessible.

Comment: Also note that you have some invalid HTML. The `options` tag has no closing brace, and I'm pretty sure you meant `option`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll remove those. I'm just trying to get the searchFormFunc to work for now.

Comment: You are trying to attach a submit-handler to a div-element not to a form element.

Comment: Please fix the syntax issues in your code. The highlighting should make it pretty clear where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @Blauharley. That is what my main issue was.

Comment: @Blauharley - if you are answering. Make an answer, not a comment, please. For the good of mankind.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard: I'll do it the next time, its a promise!

Answer (score 1):

@Blauharley answered my question. I was trying to use the addEventListener on a div and not the actual form. I changed my html to look like this and it is working now:

```
    <form id="citySearchForm">

        <div id="weather"></div>

        <p><span id="temp"></span></p>

        <p><span id="wind"></span></p>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is in the comments for some reason, but I'll but some detail on it.

As squint and Xufox rightly said, your `searchFormFunc()` actually does very little. It creates two new functions, but only in the scope of `searchFormFunc()`. That means that after `searchFormFunc()` finishes, the two functions it made will be lost to the ether.

Now, if you want to fire those functions when you call `searchFormFunc()` you should make `searchCity` and `getCityResults` into expressions instead of functions. I.E. take off the braces and the `function searchCity()` part.

If you want the functions to exists, but not to be called yet, remember that you can store functions as function objects. To do this, set a global variable `var a` up top, with the rest of your globals, then when you call your `seachFormFunc()` set `var a = function searchCity(e) {...}`, then you can call your function later by calling `a()`.